# Aspnet core deployment to IIS - HTTP Error 502.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have created the IIS site and pointed it at the deployment folder. I have enabled stdout logging and this is the error:

info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\No Managed Code\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler[1]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "KeyStoneDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
      Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\No Managed Code'.

So, I added the login to SQL with all the necessary rights. Retested in DEV - fine, but when running IIS I still get the issue. The Application Pool being used is 'No Managed Code'.

Why cant the app not connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

IIS AppPool accounts are virtual accounts, therefore, they don't actually exist as a normal user on the system.

You can not give access to networked resources using that identity. Shared\network resources like file shares and databases that need to communicate with these accounts need to have the 'domain\machinename$' with appropriate permissions.

Give 'domain\machinename$' appropriate permissions on your DB. That should do it.

Comment: I have setup a SQL Server Login and User Login that has access to the appropriate database schema. Then, I set up the correct Application Pool for aspnet core.( No Managed Code ). As the application pool identity, I used my windows admin login account. When testing, the application pool identity ( connect as ..) , I get a success message saying that the credentials are valid. However, when I browse the site I  get the error :   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\No Managed Code'. Why is this account being used when I have set the Application Pool Identity to my windows login?

Comment: Is your connection string set up properly in the appropriate appsettings.json I would check the environment that's being used. Looks like incorrect appsettings.json being used to me.

Comment: This is my connection string in appsettings.json:                                  {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=GREG-THINK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KeyStoneDb;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
   },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  } 
}

Comment: I don't see how it could be appsettings.json issue because the connection string is being found and the application pool identity is attempting to log in.

Comment: From your connection string I don't see you using SQL username... if you are using integrated security then you need to give "Yourdomain\yourmachinename$" appropriate permissions in the database ...